# Beginner: Extending a class in C#, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, class, casting, extend

Again *disclaimer disclaimer* still learning C# and OOP generally so I hope you'll be patient with me :)

I am currently working with a CMS that has a class called `FileVersion` which basically contains a list of properties pertaining to a file such as filename, filetype, size in bytes, id, date uploaded, is-latest-version, etc.

A list of `FileVersion`s is contained within a `File` which has it's own unique ID. When you want to download a particular file from the CMS, the URL is built using something like the following:

```
string URL = "/files/"+file.id.toString()+"/"+file.fileVersion.Last().filename;
```

Now for a particular control I'm working on (dealing specifically with files that are documents), it makes sense to be able to store the URL along with all the other `FileVersion` information for later use. So what I've decided to do is create my own class called `DocumentVersion` which extends `FileVersion`. This is what it looks like:

```
public partial class DocumentVersion : FileVersion
{
    public DocumentVersion() : base() { }
    public string link;
}
```

Now I should note, that it appears that I don't need to implement an interface here - but don't take that as gospel, that's why I'm here.

However when I try to cast my `FileVersion` as a `DocumentVersion` like so:

```
DocumentVersion dv = ((DocumentVersion)fileversion);
```

I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Foo.CMS.FileVersion' to type
>   'CoA.DocumentVersion'.

My inkling is that it's because I'm trying to extend a class in a different namespace from where the original resides, but like I said, OOP is relatively new to me so I could be wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help. This community has been so valuable! I just hope once I'm more skilled up I can give some back :).

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the class declaration for `FileVersion`? You may not be able to extend it

Comment: I'd love to Russ but unfortunately I can't because the class declaration for `FileVersion` is sitting in a dll I don't have the source for. In general though, how can I tell whether or not a class is extensible?

Comment: Thanks very much everyone for all your great answers. In the end I accepted Brian's because his was the most complete and the way the thread ended up going I learned everything I needed. Again, thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you trying to downcast ? i.e. take an existing `FileVersion` and declare it to be a `DocumentVersion` ?

If so, you can't do that, since what you have is nothing more than a `FileVersion`.

Instead you need to create a *new* `DocumentVersion` object. Your `DocumentVersion` constructor will take the arguments required for a `FileVersion` and then call the `FileVersion` constructor via `base()`.

Note that if you have an existing `FileVersion` object, you may want an object to *wrap* this, rather than have an object deriving from it. e.g. your `DocumentVersion` wouldn't derive from `FileVersion`, but contain a private reference to a `FileVersion`, plus additional data as required. That may be more appropriate in this scenario.

e.g. (in OO terms this is **composition**)

```
public class DocumentVersion {
   private FileVersion fv;
   private String url;
   public DocumentVersion(FileVersion fv, String url) {
      this.fv = fv;
      this.url = url;
   }
}
```

See [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pcurnow/compagg07272007062838AM/compagg.aspx) for more info on composition.

Comment: Aha! Looks like I have the cart before the horse! It sounds very much like what I want to do is wrap FileVersion rather than extend it. I will certainly google what you've suggested, but if it's a simple couple of lines, would you mind showing me how to do this?

Comment: See above. I'm a Java guy, so my C# is a little rusty. But the above should give you the idea.

Comment: Wrapping: Your DocumentVersion class would include an instance variable pointing to the FileVersion and additional field that you want to store. The problem is that you need to take care of storing this DocumentVersion yourself, you cannot just *attach* it to the existing FileVersion or File. So, you'd need to create your own `Dictionary<File, DocumentVersion>` to store the additional information. Of course, once you do that, the FileVersion reference in DocumentVersion is not really needed anymore, since it's accessible through File anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot cast your `FileVersion` to `DocumentVersion` because your fileversion variable contains a FileVersion, not a DocumentVersion. *Inheritance* means the following:

- Every DocumentVersion is a FileVersion, but
- *Not* every FileVersion is a DocumentVersion!

If the object was created as a FileVersion, it's just a FileVersion. Period. If it was created as a DocumentVersion, you can use it everywhere where you would use a FileVersion (see rule #1 above), *and* you can use the DocumentVersion features of it.

So, when *creating* the FileVersion object, you need to create a DocumentVersion instead (if you have control over that part of the code), then the cast will work. Those DocumentVersions could be stored in the same list as the FileVersions, since every DocumentVersion is also a FileVersion.

---

EDIT: Since the above two rules are so vital to understanding the OO principle, let me illustrate them with an example: DocumentVersion = dog and FileVersion = animal. Then the above rules would be: (1) Every dog is an animal, but (2) not every animal is a dog. So, you can create a list of animals, store all kinds of animals in there (dogs, cats, things that are just "animal", ...), but you cannot cast a variable of type animal to a dog, unless what is in there has been created as a dog (or as a poodle (class poodle : dog), which *is a* dog by rule (1)).

In OO terms: If you store a dog in a variable of type animal, then the *static type* of the object is "animal", and the *dynamic type* is "dog". You can only cast an element to some type T if its dynamic type is T or a subtype thereof.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make father (`FileVersion`) to act like son (`DocumentVersion`).
Only vica versa => you can make son as father.

(FileVersion)documentVersion //valid
(DocumentVersion)fileVersion //invalid (because fileVersion can't know about stuff that derived type has)

That's OOP basics.

Answer (score 1):

```
DocumentVersion dv = null;

if (fileversion is DocumentVersion)
{
    dv = fileversion as DocumentVersion;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(As most answers have said, you can't cast back up - `FileVersion` has no idea what a `DocumentVersion` is).*

One way to get around it is to copy the fields in the constructor of `DocumentVersion`

```
public partial class DocumentVersion : FileVersion
{
    public DocumentVersion() : base() { }

    public DocumentVersion(FileVersion version) : this()
    {
        this.id = version.id;
        // etc.
    }

    public string Link { get;set; }
}
```

Or create a static method on `DocumentVersion` that returns a `DocumentVersion` from the `FileVersion` you provide it, e.g:

```
public static void New(FileVersion version)
{
    this.id = version.id;
    // etc.
}
```

Another technique mentioned, is composition. You store the `FileVersion` as a property in `DocumentVersion`

```
public class DocumentVersion
{
    public FileVersion FileVersion { get;set; }
    public string Link { get;set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot convert a `FileVersion` to a `DocumentVersion` and all you need to do is add a method to get the URL, you could create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047(VS.80).aspx#cs3spec_topic3) that takes a `FileVersion`:

```
public static string GetLink(this FileVersion fileVersion) {
  return "/files/"+fileVersion.id.ToString()+"/"+fileVersion.FileVersion.Last().Filename
}
```

Note : this only works if you are using C# 3.0.